# Ubuntu 16.04 - No sound out of laptop or external monitor

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

Recently purchased a new laptop (Razer Blade Pro) and am dual booting windows and ubuntu 16.04. Windows works perfectly, Ubuntu does not. Most problems have been ironed out now, but sound has not. About 20% of the time that I boot into linux, it works fine, the rest, nothing. No sound at all. I have tried literally everything I have seen online, from pulseaudio to pavucontrol to a whole other bunch of packages I've never heard of before, but I simply cannot fix this problem. Any advice would be grateful. I'm not sure what data I will need to provide to get the ball rolling, so please let me know.

Everything below is with no external monitor, speakers, or headphones plugged in.

Output from `alsa -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Image showing audio playing, pavucontrol windows and also alsamixer. Note that auto-mute was enabled, and I turned it off (disabled) before taking this screenshot.

[image: debug]

Comment: I will say though, headphones **do** work.

Comment: Which options appear when you select a card in `alsamixer` (press F6 to open the menu)? What's the output of `pactl list short sinks`?

Answer (score 0):

pavucontrol is best for checking and adjusting Pulseaudio

try checking ALSA audio settings at same time

```
aplay -l
```

for list of ALSA playback devices

your onboard device will likely show 2 ALSA sub-devices for headphones and speakers

assuming onbard audio device is device number 0 (might be digital HDMI too)

```
alsamixer - c 0
```

check card and chip information for match to laptop specifications

use arrow keys to navigate left and right, up and down to change level
check headphone and speakers not muted (MM) use "M" key to turn on (OO)

Mute and set level to 0 for any unused playback controls,
digital/SPDIF playback may need to be muted/off for analog audio playback

check to right for auto-mute option, maybe hidden due to window width
setting auto-mute to disabled/off will have speakers remain on when headphones are plugged in

whilst making changes in alsamixer, check if pavucontrol registers any activity or change

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately no dice. I added in the output from `aplay -l` and a screenshot of the alsamixer with pavucontrol windows side by side. Changing things in alsamixer did automatically reflect in pavucontrol. It thinks its playing music, but it isn't. Note that plugging headphones in works (sound comes out fine). Restarting a few times also allows the onboard speakers to work (maybe 20% of the time).

Answer (score 0):

If the headphones do work (although I doubt that since you have them muted in your alsamixer output), then either you have the wrong output selected for pulse audio or you have a hardware problem. Since you say that the onboard speakers work **occasionally**, this indicates a hardware issue (whether faulty wiring or a mute switch that is disabling output that you are toggling without realizing it, or volume set all the way down on your connected HDMI device). Some answers don't require a extensive explanation.

Note that "Built-in Analog Stereo" doesn't necessarily mean "Built-in speakers" I have the same on my desktop without such accouterments.

To reduce the confusion, when you run `alsamixer` select F3 for Playback devices instead of F5 for all since input isn't your issue. this will remove unrelated options from your list of choices. Unmute everything that remains that shows Muted `M`

For `pavucontrol` Verify that you have selected an appropriate profile for your properly selected output from the configuration tab as shown below:
[image]

If all else fails, you might wish to review https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure. Once you've gone through that process, if you still have issues, you may have discovered a bug. If so, please follow the procedures outlined [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems) so that the developers can squash it.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows can affect Ubuntu

From the [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Razer_Blade) article on your Razer Blade Pro:

> ### Audio
>
> ---
>
> On the latest 'KabyLake' Intel CPU, if you also have a dual-boot with
> Windows, you might experience some audio issues when booting to
> Windows and restarting on Linux. The problem is no sound from the
> speakers and some cracking noises on the headphones - especially when
> using the touchpad -. No official solution has been posted yet, but a
> quick hack is to completely shut down the computer (so power off, not
> restart).

I've experienced similar problems where Windows had powered off devices when rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

## Testing ALSA

Starting off, let's test ALSA. You need to parse out the devices from `aplay`

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
```

The Laptop is easy, that's 0,0 by processes of elimination. This should buzz the laptops sound,

```
cat /dev/urandom | aplay -c 2 -f s16_le -d hw:0,3
```

For the monitor, you have card:0, device:3,7,8, you can target it like this...

```
cat /dev/urandom | aplay -c 2 -d hw:0,3
cat /dev/urandom | aplay -c 2 -d hw:0,7
cat /dev/urandom | aplay -c 2 -d hw:0,8
```

One of those should make a loud obnoxious sound. If none of those make a loud obnoxious sound, you

- likely have a bad ALSA driver, or
- the source is muted, or
- perhaps the monitor is sourcing sound from a 3.5mm aux in source and not HDMI, or you have something plugged into your sound card on the laptop (headphones)

You can always paste the result of `amixer`.

If that works, the problem is in Pulse Audio.

## Testing Pulse Audio

First we need to know what sinks you have `pacmd list-sinks`. you should see a bunch of lines like this,

```
* index: 0
```

In short, that's how Pulse indexes those sinks, you can target them like this,

```
pacat -d 0 /dev/urandom
```

That should put out a loud buzz through the Pulse sink. If it doesn't,

- the column could be 0
- the device may be muted.
- you may have a problem with Pulse

## You can play to ALSA and Pulse?

If you've test the ALSA layer, and it works. And, the Pulse daemon works. Then the only area for misconfiguration is the clients themselves. They should all be using Pulse Audio. You can use `pacmd set-default-sink` to set the default sync for the system. Make sure that the Pulse Servers clients are all using the server's default sink.